# Change cell colour on click of edit button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView in my Viewcontroller , I want to change the cell background colour only when user clicks Edit button in the cell.

What i did so far is

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskcell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! taskListCell
    cell.backgroundColor = colorMediumGreen
    // Configure the cell…
    let tableData = self.tableData[indexPath.row]
    cell.duration.text = tableData[""] as? String
    cell.taskDetail.text = tableData[""] as? String

    return cell

}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Erledigt") { (rowAction, indexPath) in

    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [editAction]
}
```

Comment: Just get the cell with the help of `IndexPath` and update that cell in `editAction `.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni : can you please explain how?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this problem :-)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Edit") { (rowAction, indexPath) in

        let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = colorLightGray

        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
    }

    editAction.backgroundColor = .red

    return [editAction]
}
```

Comment: Thats  great.. :)